# Devise not showing signed_up_but_unconfirmed flash message after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, devise-confirmable

I am working on application that uses devise confirmable. Everything is working fine but whenever I sign up a user, after succesfull creation of user, instead of devise showing signed_up_but_unconfirmed flash message (A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please follow the link to activate your account.), it is redirecting it to sessions new page and showing unauthenticated flash message(You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.).Besides this, everything of devise confirmable is working fine.

Rails 7
Ruby 3
Devise 4.8.1

Comment: please validate your controllers to propertly setup the rules for a new session creation